# PHP canonical redirect

Tags: php, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I am trying to do a canonical redirect from this url

www.mysite.com/page.php?id=1&title=aaa

To this: www.mysite.com/1_aaa

I wrote this function:

```
function canonicalRedirect($url)
{

    if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'GET')
    {
        $canonical = $url;
        if (!preg_match('/'.str_replace('/','\/',$canonical).'/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.0 301 Moved');
            header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
            header("Location: $canonical");
        }
    }
}
```

And in the page.php I put this code:

```
canonicalRedirect($url);
```

Retrieving the $url variable from a MySQL query. However when I try to run it I get this error (I am using Firefox): The page isn't redirecting properly

I am thinking that the page is self-redirecting but how can I solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Which part are you exactly retrieving from database? I mean what does your `$url` variable contain - `id=1&title=aaa` or `1_aaa`?

Comment: My $url variable contains 1_aaa

Comment: Try removing the HTTP/1.0 header, and instead add 301 as the second parametr of the location header. Also, what the url looks like?

Comment: Your question does not contain the information about what values you pass to the function.

Comment: Hi Darhazer, I tried to do as you suggested but did not work. I am passing to the function the url to which I want the page to be redirect. EG I want the page http://www.mysite.com/page.php?id=1&title=aaa to be redirected to http://www.mysite.com/1_aaa. I am passing http://www.mysite.com/1_aaa as the value of the function canonicalRedirect.

Comment: I give you another information. The 1_aaa page is redirected via htaccess like this: RewriteRule ([^/]+)_([^/]+) /page.php?id=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]

Comment: This calls for basic debugging first. Please do a `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the very beginning of your script. Additionally you should [enable error logging](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html) and follow the error log.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally I managed to solve my problem. I rewrited my function like this:

```
function canonicalRedirect($url)
{
            //Check that there is not query string in the url
    if(preg_match('/\?/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 301 Moved');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
        header("Location: $url");
    }   
}
```

Then in the page.php code I wrote this:

```
 // code to retrieve the canonical url from MySQL
 // $row is the array with the url data and $canonicalurl is obviously the canonical url


if($_GET['title'] != $row['url_title']) {

  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved");
  header('Status: 301 Moved Permanently', true);
  header("Location: ".$canonicalurl."",TRUE,301);
}
else {
}

canonicalRedirect($canonicalurl);
```

Bye!

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$canonicalURL` is not defined in your function, resulting in empty location for the redirect

Comment: is it possible with php to make such urls?

Comment: Sorry, I mispelled the post, now I'm going to edit it (I gave firstly another name to my variable)... the problem however remains

Comment: woah man also i want the answer! @FG

Comment: @AspiringAqib redirect is done via HTTP headers. With PHP, you can manipulate the HTTP headers send to the client

Comment: @AspiringAqib: mod_rewrite cannot read database, people can still 301 redirect using PHP/ASP.NET (etc) based on some value in database. OP is doing the same but he/she has got a problem on the preg_match line.